# React Native how to make ScrollView Based on dynamic Content Size

Tags: react-native

I have a component surrounded with scrollView that shows dynamically a list of items in a state array .

```
    <ScrollView>
coderef..........
  {this.state.MyList.map((ItemOfList) => {
            return (
              <Item>
               coderef.......
              </Item>
            );
          })}
coderef..........
    </ScrollView>
```

the coderef parts does not have any problem with scrolling but once MyList has more than two ItemOfList (which will increase the height) the scroll doesn't reach the end of the page anymore

Comment: do you mean, the view is not scrollable?

Comment: yes it doesn't work beceause the height of my page is dynamic it changes with the number of elements in MyList

Comment: @EyaOsmane try adding as a prop to scrollview ``style={{ height: "100%"}}``

Comment: The problem might also occur if the parent has height not set to '100%' or `flex : 1`.

Comment: nothing changes when i try style={{ height: "100%"}} and not even with flex:1 the  problem is the same

Answer (score 1):

You have to add also a maxHeight property and it'll resize automatically your scrollView based on your content, I have the field that I want to autosize at the end so I also had to add minHeight:

[multiple results autosize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf0Hb.png)

[two results autosize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XouKL.png)

```
minHeight: 200, maxHeight: '50%'
```